# HTML5 deep zoom and moving objects

Tags: javascript, html, zooming

I'm prototyping a web application that needs to be able to show moving objects on top of a background drawing. The objects are fed their positions through WebSockets, which works well.

As long as the the background is fairly simple, there is no problem. I've successfully used both Canvas and SVG to accomplish this.

To the problem: When the complexity of the background increases (i.e. file size increases), it doesn't really work anymore. It takes too long to load, to zoom and to pan. I've tried a deep zoom implementation (http://www.akademy.co.uk/software/canvaszoom/canvaszoom.php) which works OK, but there are two problems:

1. I can't seem to be able to generate (Deep Zoom Composer) a deep zoom tiles that are zoomed deep enough. The top level is very far away, which is unnecessary. The image that I use to generate the tiles is of very high resolution.
2. I keep my moving object on another canvas on top of the background canvas. How do I get the zoom levels in sync? How do I know much is one "level" percentage wise?

I don't necessarily need to use deep zoom, but I believe it needs to be some kind of server based technique, to keep the size down which is sent to the client.

By the way, the background is originally a DWG file and the solution must be plugin-less (no silverlight, flash or similar).

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand what you want, it is similar to what Google Maps does when you zooming and moving around.
Whole image is split on segments. Then when you zooming another images that are split as well are used.
So you want to stick to some rule that for example one segment can contain another 4 segments one layer lower. That way it will be much easier to calculate sizes and synchronize them.
Probably you want to have kind of coordinate system with global and local (related to layer) segment coordinates.

Comment: Well, the segments (or "tiles" as they are commonly called) are generated by a tool called Deep Zoom Composer (which will be used by the customer), so I'm not sure how much impact I can have on how they are created. I do like to understand, though, how the different tiles correlate to the x,y coordinate system of the canvas.

Comment: I've been messing around with Seadragon AJAX a little bit, which seem to be a very nice framework to work with. Any thoughts around pros and cons?

Comment: Just FYI, I made one DeepZoom example with moving objects long times ago. See this video. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekfZQuxdnzE